# Nodejs module function returns undefined, not asynchronous

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Pretty (very) new to Node so this is probably stupid. I have a module that defines various routes that I iterate over to define the app's routes. This works fine.

While setting up the route I want to call a function `checkAvailableTranslation` in another module `language` that checks whether a translation of that page exists in another language (`req.locale` being the user's favoured language that we are trying to find a match for), and if so return a URL fragment for it.

The `strings` object is loaded from a json file and contains an item `translations` that is an array of ISO country codes mapped to URL fragments.

** app.js **

```
var routes = require("./config/routing.js")
routes.forEach(function(item) {
    item.routes.forEach(function(route) {
        app.get(route.path, function(req, res) {
            var strings = require(route.strings)
            translations = language.checkAvailableTranslation(req.locale, strings.translations))
            console.log(translations) // undefined?!?!?!?!
            res.render(route.render, {
                layout: route.layout,
                strings: strings
            })
        })
    })
})
```

** strings.translations **

```
[
    { "fr": "/fr" },
    { "ar": "/ar" },
    { "es": "/es" },
    { "pt": "/pt" },
    { "de": "/de" }
]
```

** language.js **

```
module.exports = function() {
    var module = {}

    module.checkAvailableTranslation = function(language, translations) {
        translations.forEach(function(el) {
            if( el[language] ) {
                console.log(el[language]) // this logs a matched language
                return el[language] // this disappears into the ether
            }
        })
    }
    return module
}
```

So everything generally behaves as expected with `translations.forEach` iterating successfully and finding matches. However it doesn't seem to return the value back to app.js - when I output the function's return I get `undefined`.

Does the fact that `strings` is being loaded from a json file make this an asynchronous call, as if it were a database? If so (and that would need explaining), what should I be doing here to set up a promise to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning from the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback which is not possible.
You need to iterate manually over the array or write the result into a variable in the scope of your `checkAvailableTranslation` method(but still iterate over **all** items in `translations`).

Manual "forEach"

```
module.checkAvailableTranslation = function(language, translations) {
    for (
        var i = 0, translation = translations[i][language];
        i < translations.length;
        i++, translation = translations[i][language]
    ) {
        if (translation)
            return translation;
    }
}
```

Or using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
function (language, translations) {
    var res;
    translations.some(function (translation) {
        return !!(res = translation[language]);
    });
    return res;
}
```

EDIT: *Ninja approach*:

```
function n(l,t,i){return t[i|0][l]||g(l,t,(i|0)+1)}
```

Comment: oh right. is every() more the right thing to go for here?

Comment: @artparks as you wanted to return the first matched item `some` should do the job in combination with a scoped variable.

Comment: thanks. all this just because i didn't know foreach() couldn't be used in this way :/ as this function will be called on every page request it needs to be as efficient as possible. any reason to use some() over an old fashioned for() loop?

Comment: No, `some` will be slower than an old fashioned for loop(like in my first example), yet I've added an example using `some`.

Comment: Not code golf but I added a ninja approach, just call with `n(language, translations)`